# How do you get the hook shot to work in The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time 3D

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d

In The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time 3D I got the hook shot and registered it to the Y button. When I push Y to use it, it shoots out and hits something but doesn’t carry Link to the platform. I’ve tried it in areas that I have watched other people use it and it still does not work.

Is this a glitch? Did this happen because I missed out on learning Epona’s song before going to the Temple of Time to get the Master Sword. Please help because I do not want to start a new save file.

Comment: BTW, while it's very unintuitive and goes against the claimed lore, you can stick the master sword back into stone at the temple and go back to childhood. Later on it becomes a necessity.

Answer (score 4):

Hookshot pulls Link only to very specific objects: hookshot targets (white disc in white ring, often on top of a square pillar), treasure chests, torches with wood base, wooden flag poles, climbable vines or other climbable surfaces like wire fence (not all though), some tree branches, a few selected other wooden surfaces. It can also pull items to Link and stun some enemies. When aiming it, a red dot appears on the surface you're aiming at if it's in range, but it doesn't guarantee the surface can be grabbed.

Answer (score 0):

Link is only pulled to wood or certain targets. You must be trying to grapple up to something else. If you are trying to grapple to wood or targets, it is a glitch. Try closing the game and opening it again.
I hope this helps!